# google maps ios sdk geocoding query returns only 1 result

Tags: geocoding, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have integrated google maps sdk for ios in my application.
I am trying to implement the functionality where user can search for a location by address.

When the query is not specific enough , the returned result should contain more than 1 result (which is the case with google maps application on ios).

But i am getting a single result for all my searches.

Any pointers in this direction will be really helpful.

P.S I am using the google maps ios sdk geocoding example code.

Answer (score 0):

What `GMSGeocoder` offers is actually **reverse geocoding** service , that is it takes a lat-lon coordinates of a point on the map and then returns the address for the same. So unlike any partial search for geocoding, this search is based on a specific point and so the response will mostly have an accurate answer as the firstResult. The response class gives option to retrieve just firstResult (as you will see in the google maps ios sdk demo app) and also a results array. But the further results in the array are will be mostly less specific versions of the location like city address, state address, country address, etc and are not likely to give very different addresses